# Mixing Either and Maybe Monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I think I understand how to cascade Monad of the same type. I would like to combine two Monads together to perform an operation based on them :

I think the code below resume the problem :  suppose we have a function that validates that a String contains "Jo" and append "Bob" to it if it's the case, and another one that validates that the String length is > 8

The hello function would apply the first , then the second on the result of the first and return "Hello" to all that in case of success or 'Nothing' (I don't know what is this 'Nothing' btw , Left or Nothing)  in case of error.

I believe that it's around Monad transformer what I need but I could not find a concise example that would help me to start.

I precise that this is nothing theoratical as there is around Haskell package that works with Either and others that works with Maybe

```
validateContainsJoAndAppendBob :: String -> Maybe String
validateContainsJoAndAppendBob l =
  case isInfixOf "Jo" l of
    False -> Nothing
    True  -> Just $ l ++ "Bob"

validateLengthFunction :: Foldable t => t a -> Either String (t a)
validateLengthFunction l =
  case (length l > 8)  of
    False -> Left "to short"
    True  -> Right l

-- hello l = do
  -- v <- validateContainsJoAndAppendBob l
  -- r <- validateLengthFunction v
  -- return $ "Hello " ++ r
```

Comment: It's a *monad*, not a *nomad*...

Comment: edited , thanks I will invent the Nomad story about the Monads :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the practical answer given by Li-yao Xia, there's other alternatives. Here's two.

## Maybe-Either isomorphism

`Maybe a` is isomorphic to `Either () a`, which means that there's a lossless translation between the two:

```
eitherFromMaybe :: Maybe a -> Either () a
eitherFromMaybe (Just x) = Right x
eitherFromMaybe  Nothing = Left ()

maybeFromEither :: Either () a -> Maybe a
maybeFromEither (Right x) = Just x
maybeFromEither (Left ()) = Nothing
```

You can use one of these to translate to the other. Since `validateLengthFunction` returns an error text on failure, it would be a lossy translation to turn its return value into a `Maybe String` value, so it's better to use `eitherFromMaybe`.

The problem with that, though, is that this will only give you an `Either () String` value, and you need an `Either String String`. You can solve this by taking advantage of `Either` being a `Bifunctor` instance. First,

```
import Data.Bifunctor
```

and then you can write `hello` as:

```
hello :: String -> Either String String
hello l = do
  v <-
    first (const "Doesn't contain 'Jo'.") $
    eitherFromMaybe $
    validateContainsJoAndAppendBob l
  r <- validateLengthFunction v
  return $ "Hello " ++ r
```

This essentially does the same as Li-yao Xia's answer - a little less practical, but also a little less ad-hoc.

The `first` function maps the first (left-most) case of an `Either` value. In this case, if the return value from `validateContainsJoAndAppendBob` is a `Left` value, it's always going to be `Left ()`, so you can use `const` to ignore the `()` input and return a `String` value.

This gets the job done:

```
*Q49816908> hello "Job, "
Left "to short"
*Q49816908> hello "Cool job, "
Left "Doesn't contain 'Jo'."
*Q49816908> hello "Cool Job, "
Right "Hello Cool Job, Bob"
```

This alternative I prefer to the next one, but just for completeness' sake:

## Monad transformers

Another option is using Monad transformers. You can either wrap the `Maybe` in an `EitherT`, or conversely wrap an `Either` in `MaybeT`. The following example does the latter.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (MaybeT(..))

helloT :: String -> MaybeT (Either String) String
helloT l = do
  v <- MaybeT $ return $ validateContainsJoAndAppendBob l
  r <- lift $ validateLengthFunction v
  return $ "Hello " ++ r
```

This also works, but here you still have to deal with the various combinations of `Just`, `Nothing`, `Left`, and `Right`:

```
*Q49816908> helloT "Job, "
MaybeT (Left "to short")
*Q49816908> helloT "Cool job, "
MaybeT (Right Nothing)
*Q49816908> helloT "Cool Job, "
MaybeT (Right (Just "Hello Cool Job, Bob"))
```

If you want to peel off the `MaybeT` wrapper, you can use `runMaybeT`:

```
*Q49816908> runMaybeT $ helloT "Cool Job, "
Right (Just "Hello Cool Job, Bob")
```

In most cases, I'd probably go with the first option...

Comment: I like your first option.

Comment: that is really a first class answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Use a function to convert `Maybe` to `Either`

```
note :: Maybe a -> e -> Either e a
note Nothing e = Left e
note (Just a) _ = Right a

hello l = do
  v <- validateContainsJoAndAppendBob l `note` "Does not contain \"Jo\""
  r <- validateLengthFunction v
  return $ "Hello " ++ r
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want is (in the categorical sense) a natural transformation from `Maybe` to `Either String`, which the `maybe` function can provide.

```
maybeToEither :: e -> Maybe a -> Either e a
maybeToEither e = maybe (Left e) Right


hello l = do
  v <- maybeToEither "No Jo" (validateContainsJoAndAppendBob l)
  r <- validateLengthFunction v
  return $ "Hello " ++ r
```

You can use `<=<` from `Control.Monad` to compose the two validators.

```
hello l = do
    r <- validateLengthFunction <=< maybeToEither "No Jo" . validateContainsJoAndAppendBob $ l
    return $ "Hello " ++ r
```

You can also use  `>=>` and `return` to turn the whole thing into a single monstrous point-free definition.

```
hello =      maybeToEither "No Jo" . validateContainsJoAndAppendBob
         >=> validateLengthFunction
         >=> return . ("Hello " ++)
```